# Picasso java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should not happen from the main thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview, illegalstateexception, picasso

I am attempting to use Picasso to get three `Bitmap` images from a `URL`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
  Drawable d1 = new BitmapDrawable(Picasso.with(Tab2.this).load(zestimateImg1).get());
}
```

I am getting `FATAL EXCEPTION` with this code. I suspect it has to do with the fact that this should be done within `AsyncTask`, but I can't get it to work. If using that is avoidable, I would like to do this without using `AsyncTask`.

How can I get this code to run without crashing?

If the best way to do this is with `AsyncTask`, then that solution is ok.

Comment: Look again at the documentation of picasso and see where they call `get()` and how it's intended to be used.

Comment: @zapl I find this: `android.graphics.Bitmap get() Synchronously fulfill this request.` I don't understand threads so much :/

Comment: I will also accept the `AsyncTask` solution, though i must load three images. I just need this to work lol

Comment: @Brian Vanover Can you please provide your solution, actuallly i am working on the same problem.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do it outside the main thread and the snippet in the question helped me. What an irony.

Answer (score 17):

None of above worked for me instead this

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Picasso.with(Context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    });
```

Hope it may be useful for someone

Answer (score 10):

You cannot make synchronous requests in the main thread. If you dont want to use an AsyncThread then just use Picasso together with a Target.

```
Picasso.with(Tab2.this).load(zestimateImg1).into(new Target(...);
```

I recommend you save a reference to your target like so:

```
Target mTarget =new Target (...);
```

This is because Picasso uses weak references to them and they might be garbage collected before the process is finished.

Comment: Can you expand on this with an example?

Comment: There's no `with` in the newer version of Picasso

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        Log.i(TAG, "The image was obtained correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The image was not obtained");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        Log.(TAG, "Getting ready to get the image");
        //Here you should place a loading gif in the ImageView
        //while image is being obtained.
    }
});
```

Source: http://square.github.io/picasso/

`onPrepareLoad()` is called always after starting the request.
`from` can be "DISK", "MEMORY" or "NETWORK" to indicate where was the image obtained from.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
uiHandler.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Picasso.with(Context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(imageView);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same [answer of Juan José Melero Gómez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778519/2091181) but with **kotlin**:

```
val imageBitmap = Picasso.get().load(post.path_image).into(object: Target {
        override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {
            Log.(TAG, "Getting ready to get the image");
             //Here you should place a loading gif in the ImageView
             //while image is being obtained.
        }

        override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
            Log.e(TAG, "The image was not obtained");
        }

        override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
            Log.i(TAG, "The image was obtained correctly");
        }

    })
```