# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should not happen from the main thread. error in OnClick when using Picasso

Tags: android, onclick, picasso, unhandled-exception

I am making a wallpaper app, I want to set image from url as wallpaper.
I assigned url by using

```
url = intent.getStringExtra("tmp");
```

from previous activity. I called this code in ***onClick*** method.

```
  Bitmap result ;
  WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
  try {
            result= Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(url)
                    .get();
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am using picasso library to set image as wallpaper but I have a problem that I couldn't understand why this error occurs.

**Not:** ImageLoader is another class to display images.

Activity:

```
package gc.x;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ImageView image;
    String url;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
      //  intent.getStringExtra("tmp");

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image4) ;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.getApplicationContext());

        url = intent.getStringExtra("tmp");
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, image);


        if(button != null)
        button.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);






    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Bitmap result ;
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        try {
            result= Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(url)
                    .get();
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

EDIT: 
I tried a solution but it is not working. It does not give error, but nothing happens when I click the button. My New Code:

```
package gc.x;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ImageView image;
    String url;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
      //  intent.getStringExtra("tmp");

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image4) ;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.getApplicationContext());

        url = intent.getStringExtra("tmp");
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, image);


        if(button != null)
        button.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new SetWallpaperTask();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set wallpaper successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public class SetWallpaperTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap result= null;
            try {
                result = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load("https://www.geektopia.es/storage/geek/posts/2015/08/17/marshmallow.jpg")
                        .get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I defined a method that returns bitmap from url

```
   public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then a new thread in OnClick method to prevent android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try  {
                            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                            Bitmap bitmap= getBitmapFromURL(url);
                            if(bitmap!=null)
                                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                thread.start();
```

Final Activity:

```
package gc.x;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ImageView image;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
      //  intent.getStringExtra("tmp");

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image4) ;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.getApplicationContext());

        url = intent.getStringExtra("tmp");
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, image);

        if(button != null)
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try  {
                            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                            Bitmap bitmap= getBitmapFromURL(url);
                            if(bitmap!=null)
                                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                thread.start();

            }
        });

    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: original question was a simple handling of an exception. Once handled it revealed further problems in the code which the OP has changed his question to reflect. Without mention of his original question.

Placing

```
        Bitmap result= Picasso.with(this) //XX Problem Occurs Here
            .load("url") 
            .get();
```

Inside the IOException try/catch should fix this.

Imagine there is nothing to load().get() you would have an IOException. Since the possibility exists you need to handle it in case it happens.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Bitmap result;
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

    try {
        result = Picasso.with(this).load("url").get();
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Doing this should handle the exception.

Comment: Are you sure? I think it is not a solution.

Comment: Yes I tried. When I place in IOException it gives error for result bitmap firstly because it is assigned before declaration.

Comment: Does it fix the your IOException? It's not clear what is happening sorry. Is the Bitmap result above "wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);" in the try catch?

Comment: I tried this edited solution it solves IOException problem but new  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should not happen from the main thread. " occurs.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180765/picasso-java-lang-illegalstateexception-method-call-should-not-happen-from-the may be of help.

Comment: Thanks for help, I solved my problem. I will share my solution now.

Comment: I solved the original question you had. I see you changed your entire question to another existing problem my solution revealed.